# Is it possible to generate a Spheremap from a Texture2D in Unity at run-time?

Tags: unity, cubemap, skybox

I was trying to create a spheremap from a Texture2D for a skybox at run-time (Standalone build) in Unity. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do that in Unity?

In the editor you can set a texture to a cubemap and then select it's import setting as a spheremap, but I can't find a way to do this at run-time using the Unity API.

Comment: The only possible solution I've seen so far is having a sphere with a texture on the inside simulate being a spheremap, but that's not really the correct way to do a spheremap.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a spheremap for a skydome or a skysphere, instead of for a skybox?